# Android 4.4.2 Load app automatically

Tags: android, locking, lifecycle

Is it possible to have an app automatically launched and running at start up of the tablet in foreground?

Beside that, is it possible to password lock an app to avoid beeing sent to the backgroud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will called when the device gets started

```
public class AutoStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            //do your stuff
        }
    }
}
```